# Show list of "raw type" warning in IntelliJ IDEA 10

Tags: eclipse, types, intellij-idea, markers

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 10.5.2 with Java 1.6.

Having switched on the "Raw use of parametrized class" inspection I can see the offending lines highlighted in files where the problem exists, which is useful.

Is there a way to see, in one place, a list of all code in the project falling foul of such "inspections" as one can in the "Markers view" in Eclipse (see below for example). Does Eclipse (compiler) provide different/more info re generics than IntelliJ?

Example from Eclipse "Markers view" of what it'd be useful to see in IntelliJ too:

1. Point is a raw type. References to generic type Point should be
   parameterized ...
2. Type safety: The expression of type PointInfo needs unchecked conversion to conform to PointInfo ...

Answer (score 4):

Please try `Analyze` | `Inspect Code` for the whole project.

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed an option and shows the information.
But it is quite slow to produce and needs to be explicitly asked for, rather than generated immediately/automatically as code is modified. 
Is there a way to have IntelliJ do the same thing?

Comment: It works automatically on-the-fly for the currently edited file only, for project wide analysis you have to run the inspection from the Analyze menu.